# How can I intercalate two list of elements which are not comparable?

Tags: java, list, vector, tree, insert

Im trying to implement a method called "intercalate" which takes 2 list 'xs' and 'ys' and returns the intercalate of those both lists. However, the difficulty of this exercise is that the elements of those list cannot be comparated between them. The only informaticon is that they are leafs of a tree with some index. For example:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d025.png)

Here the 2 lists would be {a,e,c,g} and {b,f,d,h} and it should returns {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h}
if you notice, the index of the elements follow always the same patron. I mean if there were 4 elements in total, the index would be 0 , 2, 1 , 4.

Im letting here the methods and functions which TreeVector has, so that maybe you can help me better.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLlPE.png)

It should be noted that "Tree" is an interface which can be implemented by a Leaf or a Node. This is the interface:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiwyS.png)

At first, I tried to insert all elements in a LinkedList like this:

```
protected static <E> List<E> intercalate(List<E> xs, List<E> ys) {
    List<E> auxiliar = new LinkedList<>();
    int i = 0;
    for (E elem : xs) {
        auxiliar.insert(i,elem);
        i++;
    }
    for (E elem : ys) {
        auxiliar.insert(i,elem);
        i++;
    }
    return auxiliar;
}
```

However I noticed that a LinkedList doesnt insert the elements in order of a Tree, so now I dont know what to do.

Comment: Don't use a LinkedList if you want to maintain order. If the lists are same size, iterate over the size of one of them and insert in even index from the first list and in odd index from the second list.

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo yeah, i mean i know i have to do that in order to complete the method. However my problem that i dont know how to resolve is that in each list the elements are not in order.

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo for example for first list {a, e, c, g} whose elements are not sorted and second list {b,f,d,h} the same

Comment: I understand it better now. Can you do `Collections.sort()` over each list? I read that you can't compare elements from one list to the elements on the other list. but you can compare elements in each list, right?

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo no, i mean the elements of the list are not comparable at all, with the same list or other list, not comparable

Comment: How will you know then what to put where? Do they contain something that you can say "ah, this one goes before that one"?